# Jackson-Json, запарсить массив

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Есть String Volley connect.

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,regions, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"login response"+ response);
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
                Pojo pojo=mapper.readValue(response,Pojo.class);
                System.out.println(pojo.getSuccessPojo());


            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

JSON

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "АР Крым"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Винницкая область"
    },
```

Pojo

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)public class Pojo {
public Pojo(){}
private String success,id;

@JsonProperty("success")
public String getSuccessPojo() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccessPojo(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

Всё работает для `"success": true,`, как вытянуть информацию из `"data": []`?

Comment: А `success` почему `String`, а не `Boolean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `Pojo` должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
public class Pojo {
  private boolean success;
  private List<DataPojo> data;
  // getters & setters
}
```

А `DataPojo` выглядит как-то так:

```
public class DataPojo {  
  private String id;
  private String name;
  // getters & setters
}
```

Comment: При обращении System.out.println(pojo.getDataPojo().toString()); 
Выдает - com.example.Pojo@cb3844c,. Обьекты все есть уже, но информации самой  в них нет.

Comment: Так вы перепишите метод `toString()` у своих классов и выводите что вам надо. По дефолту он выводит имя класса и хэшкод, но это ничего не говорит о содержимом экземпляров класса.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть что-то типа такого:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)public class Pojo {
public Pojo(){}
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("success")
public String getSuccessPojo() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccessPojo(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

А парсить вот так

```
List<Pojo> myObjects = mapper.readValue(response, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Pojo.class));
```

Comment: Ага, типа `success` и `id` + `name` на одном уровне?

Comment: success просто забыл дописать